# JAXWS wsimport stopping recompile

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, wsimport

I am using NetBeans with the JaxWS maven plugin.  My app has about 5 different wsdls I need to load.  My problem is I want to stop maven or wsimport from recompiling my wsdl every time.  I would like to be able to work/compile offline.  If no connection is available do not attempt to pull down.  This seems like staleFile or Keep would fix this but this doesn't seem to help.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating a seperate project to host our webservice client.  We rebuild this project any time the interface of our service changes.  This is automated with hudson.